# javascript generated <option> tags getting wrong values from feeder function

Tags: javascript, html

I have this section of code, which gets data from a few similar loops, and returns the id of a user selected drop-down. The problem is that the id (or value, or data) which populates in a given tag is unpredictable, but always wrong.

```
 inputModeSelect();
    if(inputUnits.value != "default" && outputUnits.value != "default")
    {
        var input = inputUnits.options[inputUnits.selectedIndex].id;
        var output = outputUnits.options[outputUnits.selectedIndex].id;
        console.log(input);
        console.log(output);
```

The functions which generate the list are basically the same, and follow this pattern. inputArray, inputUnits and conversionFactor come from a function which allows the user to select between a few different classes of measurement, and are all populating correctly.

"inputUnits" is the name of the  tag which this loop handles.

```
function inputHandler(inputArray, inputUnits, conversionFactor)
{

    /*  This is the same value as is passed by inputUnits unless the 
    user updates the mode selector on the page.  */
    var inputUnitsArray = [];
    inputUnitsArray = document.getElementById("inputUnits");

    //these are returning the values I expect
    console.log(inputUnitsArray);
    console.log(inputArray);
    console.log(conversionFactor);



  /*  This section is where my problem seems to be. I test how many 
    options there are in the "inputUnits" <select> tag, and compare that 
    to the length of the array used to populate the list. This works, and
    correctly calls my "for" loop, but where I expect it to populate the 
    option.innerHTML, option.value, option.dataset, and option.id tags 
    consistantly in accordance with the passed arrays, I am getting strange
    behavior. Most recently a tag which was called "milligrams" in the 
    select menu returned "ounces" as it's .value attribute. I'm not sure how
    I can be populating those values in a single iteration from a single  
    source value and return different strings.  */
    if (inputUnitsArray.length < inputArray.length + 1)
    for(i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++)
    {
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.innerHTML = "<option>"+(inputArray[i])+"</option>";
        option.value = inputArray[i];
        option.dataset.conversionFactor = conversionFactor[i];
        option.id = inputArray[i];
        document.getElementById("inputUnits").appendChild(option);
    }

    /*  tests the value attribute of the first custom object against the 
    array generated by the feeder function, and removes everything but the 
    default object when they don't match. This section is working correctly.
    */
    if(inputUnitsArray[1].value != inputArray[0])
    {
        for (i = inputUnitsArray.length; i > 1; i--)
        {
            inputUnits.removeChild(inputUnits.lastChild);
        }
    };
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    return;
};
```

I don't know if it's relevant, but the script in question is set up to refresh about five times per second to provide the user with near real time feedback. My console logs don't do anything which would lead me to believe this is the cause of my problem though.

Comment: `option.innerHTML = "<option>"+(inputArray[i])+"</option>";` is attempting to put an `<option>` inside an `<option>`. Don’t do that. `option.textContent = inputArray[i];`, if you can count on support for `textContent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code:

```
option.innerHTML = "<option>"+(inputArray[i])+"</option>";
```

nests an `option` element inside the `option` element. It is enough to use:

```
option.innerHTML = inputArray[i];
```

The part which is creating the options isolated and working example:

```html
<select id='inputUnits'> </select>
```

```
var inputArray = ['1', '2', '3']
for(i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.innerHTML = inputArray[i];
        option.value = inputArray[i];
        option.id = inputArray[i];
        document.getElementById("inputUnits").appendChild(option);
}
```

See it working: http://jsfiddle.net/ddan/0tsto3so/1/

Comment: I appreciate that. Tonight when I have time to more thoroughly test my code, I'll accept it if this fix does resolve my issue, but initial testing is promising.

Comment: Thank you. Removing the writing in the outer html tag fixed my issue.